# apt-get says apparmor is installed, but the Docker kernel compatibility check says it's not

Tags: apt, docker, apparmor

I'm in the process of installing Docker for the first time.

In the official documentation, at [this point](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#kernel-compatibility), it says I should download and run a script (`check-config.sh`) to test whether my system has all the things needed for Docker.

When I run the script (as `docker` user), it outputs a list of dependencies categorized by importance. Of the requirements listed under "Generally necessary" (the most important ones), the only one it says I'm missing is something called `apparmor_parser`:

```
- apparmor: enabled, but apparmor_parser missing
    (use "apt-get install apparmor" to fix this)
```

but when I run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install apparmor` I get this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apparmor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apparmor is already the newest version (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.9).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
```

All the other evidence I've seen suggests apparmor is installed: `cat /sys/module/apparmor/parameters/enabled` returns `Y`, and `docker run hello-world` outputs something sensible.

The relevant part of the `check-config.sh` script goes like this:

```
if command -v apparmor_parser &> /dev/null; then
        echo "$(wrap_good 'apparmor' 'enabled and tools installed')"
else
        echo "$(wrap_bad 'apparmor' 'enabled, but apparmor_parser missing')"
        ...
```

I don't know what `command -v apparmor_parser` means. When I ran it I got no output.

I worry that if `apparmor` isn't installed, or if it is but Docker doesn't know where to find it, I could end up running Docker with missing security features. What should I do?

Linux version etc:

```
$ uname -srvmpio
Linux 4.13.0-39-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 5 16:43:10 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**UPDATE:**

`apparmor_parser` is in `/sbin/`, so the script couldn't find it. When I run `PATH=$PATH:/sbin ./check-config.sh` it appears to work. But when I run `/sbin/apparmor_parser` I get `apparmor_parser: Sorry. You need root privileges to run this programme.`. And when I run `sudo apparmor_parser` I get `Warning from stdin (line 1): apparmor_parser: cannot use or update cache, disable, or force-complain via stdin` (and it doesn't terminate until I press Ctrl+C). So it still looks to me as if it might still not be working. And I don't want to have to run Docker as root.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 That could be part of it. I can't run it as not root, but with `sudo apparmor_parser` I get `Warning from stdin (line 1): apparmor_parser: cannot use or update cache, disable, or force-complain via stdin`. What does that mean? And are you sure that adding `/sbin` to `$PATH` is a good idea?

Comment: Fair enough. Yes, that seems to work, thanks. But (going off on a tangent a bit...) does it matter that I got that error message from running `apparmor_parser` as root? And does it matter that the `docker` user can't run `apparmor_parser` directly? (`apparmor_parser: Sorry. You need root privileges to run this programme.`)